# Line breaks in \index commands cause same entries to appear as different ones in the index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

If there are two `\index{}` commands containing the same string, but one with a line
break, then that item appears as two different items in the index. See the MWE
below (copy it with the line break in the first `\index` command) where the entry is `foofoofoo barbarbar` (once in one line in the `.tex`, once broken over
a line). Is there a way to avoid that? One could escape all spaces with `~`, but then
line breaks of the entries in the index are not ideal anymore. Also, the entries
`foofoofoo~barbarbar` and `foofoofoo barbarbar` are considered different, too, so
*forgetting* to insert a tilde in one entry will also lead to a different entry. I couldn't find much/any information about line breaks in index commands interestingly...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
With editors that break lines automatically (to adhere to the, say 80, column
rule; for example Emacs), blanks in index commands are often automatically
broken over lines.

As an example to demonstrate this behavior, this leads to \index{foofoofoo
  barbarbar} (broken over lines in `.tex`) to appear as a different\clearpage
entry than the entry \index{foofoofoo barbarbar}. How can this be prevented? One
way would be to always avoid blanks in `index` commands via `~` but then the
items in the index are not broken over lines in an ideal way.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `\index` is gathered in an almost-verbatim fashion, so in the `.idx` file you get

```
\indexentry{foofoofoo   barbarbar}{1}
\indexentry{foofoofoo barbarbar}{2}
```

The MakeIndex program by default respects multiple spaces, but you can tell it not to with the `-c` command line option.

```
OPTIONS
 -c  Compress intermediate blanks (ignoring leading and trailing blanks and
     tabs).  By default, blanks in the index key are retained.
```

You can pass it with the optional argument to `\makeindex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-c]

\begin{document}
With editors that break lines automatically (to adhere to the, say 80, column
rule; for example Emacs), blanks in index commands are often automatically
broken over lines.

As an example to demonstrate this behavior, this leads to \index{foofoofoo
  barbarbar} (broken over lines in `.tex`) to appear as a different\clearpage
entry than the entry \index{foofoofoo barbarbar}. How can this be prevented? One
way would be to always avoid blanks in `index` commands via `~` but then the
items in the index are not broken over lines in an ideal way.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ... excellent, thank you very much, egreg!